# Why is it wrong to ask for sources?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, asking-questions

I understand that most of us are looking for information about events or persons from the past, maybe motivations of their acts, causes or results of what they did.

We also have a "historiography" tag. The historiography is a science about studying the history. We do allow such questions. For example, my question "how do historians treat gossip?" was not closed and was quite well received.

What is wrong with asking for sources? This is also historiography. Some sources are good, some bad and for many people it is hard to distinguish.

(I understand that some questions present lack of own effort, and they should be closed as any other question)

Comment: There a number of meta threads where the highest scoring answers (as well as the majority of answers) support 1) primary source/data/reference requests and 2) "canonical/seminal" source requests. But somehow that consensus never seems to stick when it comes to close/downvoting...

Comment: I looked up by "source" but haven't found anything. Maybe because I use a mobile application now. I will try to search with a computer. Sorry if I have made a duplicate.

Comment: Oh, not calling this a duplicate! Just expressing my support :)  -- btw the threads I was thinking of are [this](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/questions/1993/proposal-to-permit-reference-questions-on-se) and [this](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/questions/896/are-requests-for-references-appropriate-on-history-stack-exchangerevisited)

Comment: I think your question is good, but I would prefer to keep all discussion of sources in one question.  There are some very good answers on that question.

Answer (score 1):

The site doesn't like "list" questions. These are hard to answer, and evaluate objectively.

To ask a good source question, you should ask about a particular source, show what it does, and ask about the "value" of the source. A question like that can be answered and evaluated.